# IIS 6 Management Console enable with command line of dism

Tags: iis, dism

I would like to know how to enable that IIS 6 Management Console with dism command line.

I tried some command, but it was not working.

```
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /all
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-Metabase /all
```

Please tell me some ideas.

I couldn't get inform about feature name via command "dism /online /Get-features".

About feature name or command line or etc.

Comment: Did you finally fix this issue? I'm facing with the same problem

Answer (score 2):

It looks to be a little confuse to me because there isn't consistency in the names... but you should do this:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-LegacySnapIn
```

That will install IIS 6 Management Console with dism.

Regards